# Xamarin.iOS: iPhone no longer available in debug list

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

After the latest update to Visual Studio 2019 v16.11.3 my iPhone is no longer appearing in the debug list and I can't deploy anymore.
I always deployed without pairing Visual Studio to a Mac and installed iTunes instead.

I have tried restarting my iPhone, changing connection cables but nothing helped. What causes this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem is to reinstall iTunes via the Microsoft Store. Open iTunes and restart Visual Studio.
Now my iPhone gets detected again.